# How do I solve for $k = f(k)$ when it is raised to the power $v^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To solve for $k$ in the following function:

$$k^{v^2}=f(k)$$

Which of the algebraic manipulations is correct?

(1) $$k= \pm f(k)^{1/v^2}$$

or

(2)
$$k^v= \pm f(k)^{1/2} \rightarrow k = \pm f(k)^{{1/2}^{1/v}} $$

Are they equivalent, and, if so, can you provide a proof of it?

Comment: I deleted the question when I noticed a mistake, instead of editing it...

Comment: If you would like to repost your answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be $k=f(k)^{1/v^2}$ when $v$ is odd and $k=\pm f(k)^{1/v^2}$ when $v$ is even.

We will have $k^v=\pm f(k)^{1/2}$ when we have $(k^v)^2=k^{2v}=f(k)$, where in the problem you have $k^{v^2}={(k^{v})^v}=f(k)$.

Comment: [You can check this link](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/discover-fractions-and-factors/powers-and-exponents) to know how to deal with exponents better.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is totally wrong: if it was $k^v=f(k)^{1/2}$, then $f(k)=(k^v)^2=k^{2\cdot v}$ which is (in general) different from $k^{v^2}$.
The first one is actually the correct manipulation, but be careful with the sign: it has sense tu put a $\pm$ in front of the solution only if $v$ is an even integer.